# Do I need to inherit foreign keys across multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a number of tables in a MySQL database. They are defined like so:

Agencies

- AgencyID
- AgencyName

Orgs

- OrgID
- OrgName
- Agencies_AgencyID (one-to-many relationship with Agency table)

Locations

- LocationID
- LocationName
- Orgs_OrgID   (one-to-many relationship with Orgs table)
- Orgs_Agencies_AgencyID  (inherited relationship)

**Question:** do I need to include the Orgs_Agencies_AgencyID column in the Locations table? The  relationship with the Agencies table is already established in the Orgs table.

What about if I create another table linked to the Locations table? I'll need to inherit LocationID - do I need to inherit OrgID and AgencyID as well? Or is it OK to cross-reference them from the earlier tables?

Thanks if you can help ..

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to include the Orgs_Agencies_AgencyID column in the
>   Locations table?

You do not need to include `Locations.Orgs_Agencies_AgencyID`, unless as an optimization.

If you plan to run queries using all three tables, you can simply use `Orgs.Agencies_AgencyID` and not have `Locations.Orgs_Agencies_AgencyID` in Locations.

**Additionally, there is an issue with Locations table:**

1) You may need to normalize the `Locations` table, as below:

Locations

- LocationID
- LocationName

Organization_Locations

- LocationID
- Orgs_OrgID (one-to-many relationship with Orgs table)

2) As your table is now:

- 1 location is assigned to 1 organization.
- if the same location is assigned to two organizations (e.g. joint offices), you have repeating rows.

Comment: OK - is it actually a bad idea to include Orgs_Agencies_AgencyID in the Locations table? If an incorrect value is somehow entered for this which doesn't match with the value in the Orgs table then it could be hard to determine where the mistake is made ..?

Comment: Is agency a subset of organization? Doesn't this mean agencies can have different locations regardless if they are the same organization? If so, `Orgs_OrgID` is the entry that can be removed. Getting rid of one of the columns should not cause errors as this information can be obtained from the relationships. E.g. `Orgs_Agencies_AgencyID  -> Agencies_AgencyID` : you can get organization ID from Agency ID.

Comment: If Organizations should be assigned to Locations, you won't have errors by removing agency. You can however cause errors by assigning mismatched agency and organization to location.